# Why is $T:\ell^1\to(\ell^\infty)'$ isometric

Tags: functional-analysis

The map $T:\ell^1\to (\ell^\infty)', (Tx)(y)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_ny_n$ is isometric, but not surjective.

According to my book it is easy to prove that $T$ is isometric, but I don't quite know how to show this. I think we have to show that
$$\left|T(x)(y)\right|=\|y\|_{\ell^\infty}$$
but I don't really know how to even start this.

Comment: No, that $T$ is isometric means $\lVert Tx\rVert_{(\ell^\infty)^\ast} = \lVert x\rVert_{\ell^1}$, and that means $$\sup \{ \lvert (Tx)(y)\rvert : \lVert y\rVert_{\ell^\infty} \leqslant 1\} = \lVert x\rVert_{\ell^1}.$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What we have to show is that the norm of the linear functional $T(x)$ is $\lVert x\rVert_1$. This means that $$\lVert T(x)\rVert:=\sup_{y\in \ell^\infty,y\neq 0}\frac{|T(x)(y)|}{\lVert y\rVert_\infty}=\lVert x\rVert_1,$$ but not that equality $\frac{|T(x)(y)|}{\lVert y\rVert_\infty}=\lVert x\rVert_1$ holds for any $y$.

Notice that 
$|T(x)(y)|\leqslant \sup_j|y_j|\cdot\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}|x_k|=\lVert x\rVert_1\cdot \lVert y\rVert_\infty$, hence $\lVert T(x)\rVert\leqslant \lVert x\rVert_1$.

For the reverse equality, consider $y$ where $y_k=1$ if $x_k\gt 0$, $y_k=-1$ if $x_k$ is negative and $y_k=0$ if $x_k=0$.

Comment: okay, I understand that. Thank you!